# How to get the MSOnlineBackup Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to manage the Azure Online Backup from PowerShell.

There is a set of Cmdlets called MSOnlineBackup.  See [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249523.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249523.aspx).

When I try to run:

```
Import-Module MSOnlineBackup
```

I get:

> The specified module 'MSOnlineBackup' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

On the technet page it states that it is included in `4.0.4.0`, If I run:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

It returns:

```
Major: 4
Minor: 0
Build: -1
Revision: -1
```

I am running `Windows 8.1`.

As you can probably tell I am no Powershell expert.

I have also tried installed the Azure Backup Agent, but it says it needs a Server operating system.

**Can anyone tell me how I can get the `MSOnlineBackup` module on my machine so I can start automating `Windows Azure Backup`?**

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a server where the agent is installed, and want to develop scripts against that module on your workstation, is that correct?

Comment: Yes - I have solved this issue now using remoting. I am new to Powershell, so really didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work using remoting.

I have the full script I used here:

http://www.gregpakes.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-setup-email-alerts-for-when-windows-azure-backup-fails/